# Python does not see google-auth-httplib2

Tags: python, package, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, youtube-analytics-api

I am trying to set up a youtube API with Python [following this instruction](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query#python). But when I get to the point where I run the script, go to the authorization flow, open the link and copy the code to the terminal I get this error:

> ValueError: Credentials from google.auth specified, but google-api-python-client is unable to use these credentials unless google-auth-httplib2 is installed. Please install google-auth-httplib2.

When I try to install them using:

```
pip3 install google-auth-httplib2
```

I get

```
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-httplib2 in /Users/t1009/.conda/envs/google/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.3)
```

Any idea what may cause this error?

Adding my code below:

```
import os
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
        

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtubeAnalytics'
API_VERSION = 'v2'
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = '/Users/t1009/file.json'
def get_service():
  flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
  credentials = flow.run_console()
  return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)

def execute_api_request(client_library_function, **kwargs):
  response = client_library_function(
    **kwargs
  ).execute()

  print(response)

youtubeAnalytics = get_service()
execute_api_request(
    youtubeAnalytics.reports().query,
    ids='channel==MINE',
    startDate='2017-01-01',
    endDate='2017-12-31',
    metrics='estimatedMinutesWatched,views,likes,subscribersGained',
    dimensions='day',
    sort='day'
)
```

Comment: May i suggest having a look at this tutorial from the Google analytics api, its probably a little more up to date it may help you get things working https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py  While you wait for someone with more python knowledge then me to respond